# Unable to ssh to launchpad via bazaar

Tags: ssh, rsa, bazaar, launchpad

I have added my rsa public key to my launchpad account and then when I am trying to do "ssh -v bazaar.launchpad.net" I am getting permission denied(public key) with the message "launchpad user doesn't have a registered ssh key."

Full error log.

```
ankur@ankur-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ ssh -v bazaar.launchpad.net
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bazaar.launchpad.net [91.189.95.84] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ankur/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ankur/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ankur/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ankur/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ankur/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ankur/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ankur/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ankur/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Twisted
debug1: no match: Twisted
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 9d:38:3a:63:b1:d5:6f:c4:44:67:53:49:2e:ee:fc:89
The authenticity of host 'bazaar.launchpad.net (91.189.95.84)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 9d:38:3a:63:b1:d5:6f:c4:44:67:53:49:2e:ee:fc:89.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'bazaar.launchpad.net,91.189.95.84' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ankur/.ssh/id_rsa
Launchpad user 'ankur' doesn't have a registered SSH key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ankur/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ankur/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ankur/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Here is my sshd_config

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

and ssh_config

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

I am working on ubuntu machine.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your SSH configuration. How do you tell SSH to use your local key?

Comment: @A.L please check the edited post. I have added config files also.

Comment: You added the SSHD server configuration, it won't help here, sorry. You should post the client configuration: the content of the `~/.ssh/config` file ([example here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/)) instead.

Comment: There is no config file in ~/.ssh. Sorry for such naive question I am newbie. Do I have to create it ?

Comment: You said *I have added my rsa public key* but it looks like you initiate the ssh connection without specifying the rsa key. Is `ankur` your username on Launchpad? Is `/home/ankur/.ssh/id_rsa` your private key? Did you copy the public key on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Launchpad user 'ankur' doesn't have a registered SSH key

You didn't add your public key into Launchpad, if your username there is relly `ankur`:

https://launchpad.net/~ankur

You need to add the key (`/home/ankur/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) using web interface and when it will show up on the above url, you will be able to connect.

If it is not your username, then give a try with `ssh -v username@bazaar.launchpad.net`, but make sure your key is visible on https://launchpad.net/~username (substitute the `username` for your real username on bazaar).

Comment: @cryptok263 Please, click the tick on the left of my answer to mark it as solution.